# No permission to write APN settings?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Is there a way to insert a new APN on the "telephony/carriers" content provider? 
I have seen that it used to be possible on old versions of the Android OS. But I would like to know if there is a way to display the add APN activity and fill the fields with Extras so the user only has to accept.

Thanks in advance!